# Observable is deprecated in rxdart 0.23.1

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I just upgraded to `rxdart 0.23.1` and suddenly I am getting errors wherever I have used the `Observable` class. I have read about the breaking changes in the documentation and it has specified to use the `rxdart_codemod` package which I have integrated in my `pubspec.yaml` file and running the following command `pub global activate rxdart_codemod` throws the `-bash: pub: command not found` error. I have installed `flutter` properly and `flutter doctor` also seems to be running fine. Is there some other class that have replace `Observable`, couldn't find anything about it in the docs. Of course I can replace the `Observable` with the `Stream` from Dart language but really interested to know what path does the `rxdart` package takes as it specifies it is taking advantage of the `dart extension`.Using methods like `combineLatest2` is not possible with `Dart's Stream` so it won't be a good choice for replacement?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The `Observable` can be replaced by `Stream` as I mentioned in the question but if you are using methods like `combineLatest2` from `Observable`, then just replace `Observable` by abstract class `Rx` so you can use `Rx.combineLatest2`

Answer (score 44):

Rxdart no longer needs a custom class to work.

It now relies on extension methods, which is a recent Dart feature (Dart 2.6) to implement all of the `Observable` features directly on `Stream`.

You can safely replace all your  `Observable` by `Stream`.

Comment: Then how do I use methods like combineLatest2 with Stream, that won't be possible

Answer (score 17):

Use `Rx.combineLatest2` rather than `Observable.combineLatest2`

Observable no longer work!

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
flutter pub global activate rxdart_codemod
```

instead of `pub global activate rxdart_codemod`.

Another option is to replace your `Observable` by `Stream`.

Answer (score 4):

rxdart document changelog 0.23.0 :

```dart
ValueObservable -> ValueStream
ReplayObservable -> ReplayStream
ConnectableObservable -> ConnectableStream
ValueConnectableObservable -> ValueConnectableStream
ReplayConnectableObservable -> ReplayConnectableStream
```

Answer (score 3):

In [rxdart 0.26.0](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart/versions/0.26.0) I'm using [CombineLatestStream<T, R> class](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html) with [combine2<A, B, R> method](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream/combine2.html):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'validators.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class Bloc extends Validators {
  final _email = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  final _password = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  Stream<String> get email => _email.stream.transform(validateEmail);
  Stream<String> get password => _password.stream.transform(validatePassword);
  Stream<bool> get submitValid => CombineLatestStream.combine2(email, password, (email, password) => true);

  Function(String) get changeEmail => _email.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changePassword => _password.sink.add;

  dispose() {
    _email.close();
    _password.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rxdart now implements it in **RX**.combineLatest2