# how to convert rxdart Observable to Stream

Tags: flutter, rxdart

I was looking at code at git for [firebase auth](https://github.com/fireship-io/flutter-base) and it works fine, but a problem came when, I upgrade dependencies, particularly for [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) from ^0.21.0 to current (^0.24.1), I see other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336428/observable-is-deprecated-in-rxdart-0-23-1) that refer to

> The Observable can be replaced by Stream
> in accepted answer. I am able to change

```
Observable<FirebaseUser> user; // firebase user
..
user = Observable(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);
```

to

```
Stream<FirebaseUser> user; // firebase user
..
user = _auth.onAuthStateChanged;
```

but

```
Observable<Map<String, dynamic>> profile; // custom user data in Firestore
..
profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) {
      if (u != null) {
        return _db
            .collection('users')
            .document(u.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Observable.just({});
      }
    });
```

I tried

```
Object profile;
..
user.map( (FirebaseUser u) {
      if (u != null) {
        return _db
            .collection('users')
            .document(u.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Stream.empty();
      }
    });
```

But it does not get trigger the listen and the user profile is not read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this

```dart
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> profile = user.switchMap((u) {
      if (u != null) {
        return _db
            .collection('users')
            .document(u.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Stream.value({});
      }
    });
```